# datetime to date in QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis-3

I have a string column with a datetime in it, I want to drop the time and reformat the column to date format.
In field calculator I type:

```
to_date( (EndDate), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

This gives the following error:

```
Eval Error: Cannot convert '2020-07-15 15:12:55' to Date
```

How do I manage this?

Comment: What is the current column type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I advice you to use the `format_date` method like this:

`format_date( "Enddate" , 'yyyy/MM/dd')`

or the `to_date` method without specifying a format:

`to_date( "Enddate" )`

In both cases, the result is `2020-07-15`.

Comment: Beat me by a minute.

Comment: Wouldn't 'yyyy/MM/dd' give "2020/07/15" rather than "2020-07-15", which would need "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Comment: If it's a Date field, the result will be "2020-07-15", QGIS automatically stores with the separator "-" and you can't overwrite it. But if your field is a text field, then the result will be "2020/07/15".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
to_date(substr("EndDate",1,10)
```

edit: Ah, Vincent Bré was a bit faster apparently, and his solution is probably cleaner as well, but this one works also.