# to_date arranging dd/MM/yyy

Tags: qgis-3, date

I have a column as a string `10/12/2020 13:14:39` I want to convert it to Date format (I'll do that using the refactor tool later). First I need to rearrange this so the time is discarded and the `dd/MM/yyyy` is arranged as `yyyy/MM/dd`.

I'm using field calculator, how do I do this?

I've tried `to_date("CreatedAt", 'dd/MM/yyyy')` and `format_date("CreatedAt", 'dd/MM/yyyy')` neither give the correct result.

Comment: This recent question will help you with removing the time: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382321/datetime-to-date-in-qgis-field-calculator

Comment: my previous question, as you might expect I did try that, bit it returns `'0001/01/01'` so while removing the time clearly not the way to do it.

Comment: QGIS passes the string parsing off to QT with https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1 (You can get to the help from `Edit/Select/Select Features by Expression/Date and Time/to_date` and then description should point to the QDate::fromString help text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are starting with a datetime string, you can parse it fully and format the result as a plain date string in one step:

```
format_date(to_datetime('10/12/2020 13:14:39',
   'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),
   'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

or

```
format_date(to_datetime("CreatedAt",'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

(Note the "Preview: '2020/12/10'" in the `Edit/Select/Select by Expression` window below:
[image]

The documentation for the QGIS `to_data` and `to_datetime` expression's `format` attribute and its parsing is in QT as https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1 and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString .  You can find your way to those through the QGIS expression function description text.

Answer (score 1):

Surely there's a better way, after a random guess I got this.

```
Substr("CreatedAT",0,-9)
To_date("CreatedAt", format('dd/MM/yyyy'))
Format_date("EndDate",'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

I'll leave this here for a while to give people the chance for a more eloquent way to do this.

Comment: Side question, anyway to pipe these together?

Comment: You can nest them.  I tried `Format_date(To_date(Substr('10/12/2020 13:14:39',0,-9), format('dd/MM/yyyy'))
,'yyyy/MM/dd')`. in `Edit/Select/Select by Expression` and the  preview on the bottom showed '2020/12/10'